# Laravel 9 fatal error in Scheduler with Traits

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-artisan

I have a serious problem and I have tried everything to solve it without success. I am trying to call the **Traits ParamTrait** and **MsgTrait from** a **Scheduler (Command)** called **MsgCron**. Traits work fine for me throughout the app except Command.

Here my code MsgCron.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;
namespace App\Console\Commands;

use Illuminate\Console\Command;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

use App\Models\Cita;

class MsgCron extends Command
{

    protected $signature = 'msg:cron';


    protected $description = 'Command description';


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }
    
 use ParamTrait;
 use MsgTrait;


    public function handle()
    {

        $dia = date("d");
        $mes = date("n");
        $ano = date("Y");
        Log::channel('balancemed')->info($dia.$mes.$ano);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

My composer.json:

```
    "autoload": {
        "files": [
                "app/helpers.php",
                "app/Traits/MsgTrait.php",
                "app/Traits/ParamTrait.php",
                "app/Console/Commands/MsgCron.php"
            ],
```

Running the php artisan schedule:run command gives me a fatal error:

```
ubuntu:~/environment/balancemed $ php artisan schedule:run
PHP Fatal error:  Trait "App\Console\Commands\ParamTrait" not found in /home/ubuntu/environment/balancemed/app/Console/Commands/MsgCron.php on line 12
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/environment/balancemed/artisan:0
PHP   2. require() /home/ubuntu/environment/balancemed/artisan:18
PHP   3. ComposerAutoloaderInita6e7bc892212647700001d53e511801f::getLoader() /home/ubuntu/environment/balancemed/vendor/autoload.php:7
PHP   4. composerRequirea6e7bc892212647700001d53e511801f($fileIdentifier = 'c272475c5c4e0eb0a144305d0ca49ad6', $file = '/home/ubuntu/environment/balancemed/vendor/composer/../../app/Console/Commands/MsgCron.php') /home/ubuntu/environment/balancemed/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:61
PHP   5. require() /home/ubuntu/environment/balancemed/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php:71
```

Al ejecutar el comando composer dumpautoload me arroja el siguiente error:

```
ubuntu:~/environment/balancemed $ composer dumpautoload
Generating optimized autoload files
Class App\Http\Controllers\MsgTrait located in ./app/Traits/MsgTrait.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
Class App\Http\Controllers\ParamTrait located in ./app/Traits/ParamTrait.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping.
> Illuminate\Foundation\ComposerScripts::postAutoloadDump
PHP Fatal error:  Trait "App\Console\Commands\ParamTrait" not found in /home/ubuntu/environment/balancemed/app/Console/Commands/MsgCron.php on line 12
Fatal error: Trait "App\Console\Commands\ParamTrait" not found in /home/ubuntu/environment/balancemed/app/Console/Commands/MsgCron.php on line 12
```

I have tried with **php artisan optimize** and nothing. It also gives me an error.

Can somebody help me ?

Comment: You should add your trait path to the MsgCron.php. use App\Http\Traits\MsgTrait; and use App\Http\Traits\ParamTrait;

Comment: Why don't you use proper namespacing for your classes? Using `App` as a PSR4 namespace looks like a better option than putting all files into the classmap manually

Comment: Also, why did you try to put `MsgCron.php` into two namespaces? One line, with the namespace you really want to use, should be enough

Comment: @NicoHaase In which two namespaces do you say I put it?

Answer (score 1):

You should add your trait path to the `MsgCron.php`

```
 use App\Http\Traits\MsgTrait; 

 use App\Http\Traits\ParamTrait;
```

---

Your Class Should Be Like This
use App\Http\Traits\MsgTrait;

```
 use App\Http\Traits\ParamTrait;

       class MsgCron extends Command
        {
  use MsgTrait; 

  use ParamTrait;

           protected $signature = 'msg:cron';
    
    
        protected $description = 'Command description';
                       ...
        }
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Comment: This works for me. The truth is I'm not very clear why. When invoking the Traits from a Controller it works for me with the namespace. But when doing it from a Scheduler Command it doesn't work the same.